# Scale full screen canvas to fit content as window changes size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Basically, I have a canvas that draws a grid. When the window changes sizes, it refreshes the grid and scene to fill the entire screen with a grid.

When I resize my browser window to a smaller size, I would like the grid and everything inside the canvas to shrink with it, while keeping the grid boxes a square shape. Websites like [Agar.io](http://Agar.io) use this with their canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function resize() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}


function createMap() {
  var gridOptions = {
    majorLines: {
      separation: 30,
      color: '#e8e8e8'
    }
  };
  drawGridLines(canvas, gridOptions.majorLines);
  return;
}

function drawGridLines(canvas, lineOptions) {
  var iWidth = canvas.width;
  var iHeight = canvas.height;
  ctx.strokeStyle = lineOptions.color;
  ctx.strokeWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  var iCount = null;
  var i = null;
  var x = null;
  var y = null;
  iCount = Math.floor(iWidth / lineOptions.separation);
  for (i = 1; i <= iCount; i++) {
    x = (i * lineOptions.separation);
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, iHeight);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  iCount = Math.floor(iHeight / lineOptions.separation);
  for (i = 1; i <= iCount; i++) {
    y = (i * lineOptions.separation);
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(iWidth, y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  ctx.closePath();
  return;
}

function refresh() {
  resize();
  createMap();
}
window.onresize = function() {
  refresh();
}
refresh();
```

```css
body,
html {
  align-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainCanvas {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
```

In other words, the view of the canvas is like a bird's eye, and if there are 10 grid boxes from the center to the left side of the screen. When the window is enlarged completely, the screen would keep that same number or grid boxes from the center to the left side as it would when the browser window is resized to a smaller state. (Of course, depending on the screen ratio, it could be 10 grid boxes more or less, but roughly around there)

I tried setting the canvas size with CSS to `100%` on the width and height, but that caused the grid squares to become blurry rectangles.

What can I add to cause the elements in the canvas to shrink and grow with the windows size?

Comment: try with `100vh` and `100vw` for height and width

Comment: Currently, the JS overrides the CSS set width and height. And without the JS, it scales the grid boxes to blurred rectangles, like the `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` does.

Comment: Clarification question: you want 20 cells from left to right, but the top-bottom cell count doesn't matter? Or do you want the top-bottom cell count to also be 20 (or some other fixed number)?

Comment: Each side should roughly stay the same.  Width could stay around 20 cells left to right,  and 10 cells top and bottom. The top and bottom would fluctuate more depending on the browsers window size. Even if they are 5 units off when changing size,  that works for my case as long as its scaling unlike my current case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample where the elements in the canvas shrink and grow with the windows size:

```
<style>body{margin:0}</style>
<canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>


<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function resize() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var gridOptions = {
        majorLines: {
        separation: 20,
        color: '#e8e8e8'
        }
    };
    drawGridLines(canvas, gridOptions.majorLines);
}

function drawGridLines(canvas, lineOptions) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = lineOptions.color;
    ctx.strokeWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();

    var size = Math.floor(canvas.width / lineOptions.separation);
    for (var i = 1; i <= lineOptions.separation; i++) {
        var x = (i * size);
        ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    for (var i = 1; i <= Math.floor(canvas.height / size); i++) {
        var y = (i * size);
        ctx.moveTo(0, y);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.closePath();
}

window.onresize = function() { resize(); }
resize();
</script>
```

Here is a live sample:

https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvasResize2.html

Comment: That worked perfectly! What exactly made the difference?

Comment: @TomJaquo I simplified your code, remove a lot of the CSS, compare with yours to see the differences